# Swift JSON Duration

Tags: json, swift, uilabel, reload

I get datas from the url with JSON. When I printing the variable of berabereOran, it shows in 1 or 2 seconds on the Xcode console. But it shows in uilabel in 8 or 10 seconds. I don't know because of what.

Note: In my other project, I used tableView, because of this, I added this code: `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { self.tableView.reloadData() }` 
But this time, I don't use tableView. What should I write here?

**MY CODES:**

```
let urls = NSURL(string: "http://gigayt.com/mackolik/?code=101")
let sessions = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(urls!){

    data, response, error -> Void in

    if (error != nil){ print(error) }

    do {

        if let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary {

            let evsahibiLogo:String = jsonResult["ev-sahibi-logo"] as! String
            let deplasmanLogo:String = jsonResult["deplasman-logo"] as! String

            let berabereOran:String = jsonResult["berabere-oran"] as! String

            print(berabereOran) //shows in 1-2 seconds
            self.macsonusifirLabel.text = "(\(berabereOran))" //shows in 8-10 seconds

        }


        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

            //self.tableView.reloadData()

        }

    }

    catch { print(error) }

}

sessions.resume()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one :-

```
let urls = NSURL(string: "http://gigayt.com/mackolik/?code=101")
let sessions = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(urls!){

data, response, error -> Void in

if (error != nil){ print(error) }

do {

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

    if let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary {

        let evsahibiLogo:String = jsonResult["ev-sahibi-logo"] as! String
        let deplasmanLogo:String = jsonResult["deplasman-logo"] as! String

        let berabereOran:String = jsonResult["berabere-oran"] as! String

        print(berabereOran) //shows in 1-2 seconds
        self.macsonusifirLabel.text = "(\(berabereOran))" //shows in 8-10 seconds

    }
   }


}

catch { print(error) }

}

 sessions.resume()





    }
```